# Combine then count combination of text in cells in a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an attendance table that I need to verify every day. Every day different employees are billed on different projects, locations, and hours. Each has individual columns while the employees have an individual row in a table.

I need to be able to extract the name, project, location and hours billed for each employee and then count the number of hours billed total for all combinations.
[This is what I intend to do. D14 to D21 need to combine the data from the F and G column with a space between them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mhcd.png)

SO far I have been using a really long and nasty nested if statement and then concatenated the results. But since the table has now grown very large with a lot of useless information added, it has become really difficult to sort out the required information from the relevant columns and incorporate them into the formula.

Note: Is there any way to use the tablet header to extract the non-repeating cells in the columns and then use those to filter out the data.

Comment: Seems like a simple `INDEX/MATCH` could extract the data for each employee Platform/worktype/workhours.  I don't understand why you need any kind of `IF` statement from the data you have presented.  Use `MATCH` to get the row number into the top table; and then `INDEX` to extract the information.  eg `index(topTable,match(empl_nameORnum,top_table,0),col_num)`.  Just repeat for the three types of information you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe you need to provide more information as it seems like a pivot table would work.

Comment: I am noob in Excel. The easiest and quickest solution I came up with in work hours was an if statement. I hate making it work on daily reports. I will try your suggestion. The commands are new for me. I will study them and make them work. Thank you Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: gns100, please let me know what more information you require.